# Editing entire row in .csv using Pandas and feeding to KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn, knn

I am new to applied machine learning and there is this dataset which includes a column of percentage of cocoa present in a chocolate. But when I feed that column to fit() function of the KNeighborsClassifer it throws the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himanshu/ML Tut-2/ML_tut2.py", line 13, in <module>
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 765, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 542, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 402, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 72%
```

My code is this;

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd

choco = pd.read_csv('flavors_of_cacao.csv')

X = choco['Cocoa']
y = choco['Name']

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It is clear that the fit() function needs a float number in the cocoa column but it is getting '%' symbol along with the number which cannot be converted to float without manipulations.

Please help me to fix this problem.

EDIT:

I have edited my CSV and removed the '%' signs from it, but now I am getting the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himanshu/ML Tut-2/ML_tut2.py", line 14, in <module>
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 765, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 552, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 173, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1346, 449]
```

The new code is;

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('chocos.csv')

X = df[['Cocoa']]
y = df['Name']

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For reference, the dataset is [this](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/chocolate-bar-ratings).

Comment: check the dtypes  of your data using `choco.dtypes`. when using fit all columns should be int or float

Answer (score 0):

Just use the values from that column without the percent symbol:

```
X = [[float(val.replace('%',''))] for val in choco['Cocoa']]
```

Comment: Did the same thing as you told but still getting ValueError.

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1346, 449]